# dynamic resource publishing in restbed

Tags: c++, rest, restbed

I am using restbed.
I have an endpoint where a user can request (POST) to create a new resource. Once this endpoint is called, I would like to publish the resource under a new URI and return it to user, so that he/she can access it.

How should I proceed to achieve dynamic resource publishing in restbed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we've not implemented this feature. It is however on our road map for the near future.

Please feel free to have a crack at implementing and submitting a pull-request.

**Top of my head steps required**

1. Remove runtime checking from [Service::publish](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/blob/master/source/corvusoft/restbed/service.cpp#L245) and [Service::suppress](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/blob/master/source/corvusoft/restbed/service.cpp#L276).
2. In a thread safe manner update the Service::m_resources.

If you open a [ticket](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/issues/new) as 'Runtime modifications' we can further discuss this feature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have opened a ticket and will try to add this feature by myself.